# How can I add a react component inside an iframe?

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I have a chatbot component and I need to put it inside an iframe, how can I do that? Do I need to use a package for that? It's part of a design I received, and I'm not sure why an iframe is required :-/

Comment: Akhila can you elaborate on the issue?

Comment: @Akhila you cannot directly embed the react component inside an iframe. So if your chatbot application is hosted at some server that is having your react component. And then you can embed the URL in the src attribute of your iframe.

Comment: No the application is in the project itself. Not hosted yet.. Is there any way to do that? @VenkateshChitluri

Comment: It's just the front end part that I'm doing with react and I needed to put a component I created inside an iframe? Or can I add that as an html? I'm not sure @FahadAshraf